# IF with multi MATCH Comparison Operators

Tags: powershell

I facing with create shortest code for matching multiple words in single line.
My script file name could have long random name, but its always contains part of bellow names quoted in code.

This bellow code unfortunately does't work fine:

```
$ScriptFileName = (Get-Item $PSCommandPath).Basename

If (($ScriptFileName -match "Report", "Global", "Monthly")) {
    Write-Output "All days"
} ElseIF (($ScriptFileName -match "Day", "Hour", "Present")) {
    Write-Output "Today"
} Else {
    Write-Output "Other file name"}
    
Pause
```

Output of this code is always caching last Else - "Other file name".
I think my problem here is **-match** isn't best operator for part of multiple file names.

Working code with **-match** is like that:

```
$ScriptFileName = (Get-Item $PSCommandPath).Basename

If (($ScriptFileName -match "Reaport") -or ($ScriptFileName -match "Global") -or ($ScriptFileName -match "Monthly")) {
    Write-Output "All days"
} ElseIF (($ScriptFileName -match "Day") -or ($ScriptFileName -match "Hour") -or ($ScriptFileName -match "Present")) {
    Write-Output "Today"
} Else {
    Write-Output "Other file name"}
    
Pause
```

But is quite annoying to write it like this way :|

I also tried with operator: "-in", but its can't match only part of file name, right?

Can someone have some better idea - is this can be in possible shortest and clearer way written?

Comment: How about `$ScriptFileName -match "Report|Global|Monthly"`?

Comment: Match is using Regex which has an | operator for 'OR'.  Use : -match "Report | Global | Monthly"

Comment: Thanks - it was exactly what I looking for :)
..and was not on Microsoft documentation page: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#matching-operators

@jdweng thanks for extra explain it

Comment: If you want to learn more about regex ... [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: Documentation does show Regex : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#regular-expressions-substitutions

Answer (score 2):

Allowing *multiple* patterns as the RHS of `-like` and `-match` - so as to return `$true` if *any* of them match - is *not* implemented in PowerShell as of 7.3.2, but would be a helpful future improvement - [GitHub issue #2132](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2132) asks for just that.

---

[Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) has provided the crucial pointer: use the **[regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) [*alternation* construct `|`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#alternation-constructs)**, to match multiple patterns using with a *single* regex string:

```bash
if (($ScriptFileName -match 'Report|Global|Monthly')) { # ...

# With an array variable as input, using the -join operator.
$patterns = "Report", "Global", "Monthly"
if (($ScriptFileName -match ($patterns -join '|'))) { # ...
```

The **alternative is to use [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)**, which *does* support multiple patterns; with the `-Quiet` switch, it returns `$true` in case of a match, like `-match`:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
# You may even omit quoting around the patterns in this simple case.
if ($ScriptFileName | Select-String -Quiet "Report", "Global", "Monthly") { # ...
```

<sup>Note: `-Quiet` additionally ensures that matching against multiple inputs *stops* once a match is found.</sup>

---

The `Select-String` approach, while slower than `-match`, has the advantage that you can **opt to have the patterns interpreted as *literal* substrings** rather than as *regexes*, namely with with the **`-SimpleMatch`** switch:

```bash
# -SimpleMatch treats the patterns as *literals*.
# Without it, an error would occur, because the patterns aren't valid *regexes*.
'A * is born', 'A+', 'No match' | Select-String -SimpleMatch *, +
```

By contrast, `-match` *invariably* treats its RHS string operand as a regex, so if you want to treat the search strings as *literal* substrings, you'll have to `\`-escape regex *metachacharacters*, such as `.`, `*` and `+`, or call [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape) on the string as a whole:

```bash
# With metacharacter-individual \-escaping:
# Note that -match, as all comparison operators, can operate on an 
# *array of inputs*, in which case it acts as a *filter* and returns
# a *subarray of matching strings* (and the automatic $Matches variable is then 
# *not* populated).
'A * is born', 'A+', 'No match' -match (('\*', '\+') -join '|')

# With whole-pattern escaping:
'A * is born', 'A+', 'No match' -match (('*', '+').ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')
```

---

**Further considerations:**

- Unfortunately, **PowerShell has *no* operator for *literal* substring matching** (but does offer `Select-String -SimpleMatch`, as discussed): `-match` uses *regexes*, `-like` uses [*wildcard expressions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)) and matches input strings *in full*. *Escaping* is needed in order for these operators to treat a pattern as a literal string (as already shown for `-match` above); to do this *programmatically* is cumbersome:

  ```bash
  $pattern = '*' 

  # Same as:
  #  'A * is born' -match '\*'
  'A * is born' -match [regex]::Escape($pattern)

  # Same as:
  #  'A * is born' -like '*`**'
  'A * is born' -like ('*{0}*' -f [wildcardPattern]::Escape($pattern))
  ```
- The **[`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains) operator** - despite its similarity in name to the `[string]` type's [`.Contains()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Contains) *method* - **does *not* perform substring matching** and instead **tests whether a collection/array contains a given (single) element *in full***. The **[`-in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin) operator behaves the same**, albeit with reversed operands:

  ```bash
   # -> $true, but only because search string 'two' 
   # matches an array element *in full*.
   'one', 'two', 'three' -contains 'two' 

   # Equivalent -in operation.
   'two' -in 'one', 'two', 'three'
  ```
- Using the **`.Contains()` method** - available **on a *single* input string and with a *single* substring to search for** - is an option, but this method is *invariably case-sensitive* in *Windows PowerShell*; in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), case-*insensitivity* is available on demand (whereas it is the *default* for PowerShell's operators, which offer `c`-prefixed variants such as `-cmatch` for case-sensitivity). The workaround for Windows PowerShell is to use the [`.IndexOf()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.IndexOf) method:

  ```bash
  $substring = '* is' 

  # Case-SENSITIVE
  'A * is born'.Contains($substring)

  # Case-INSENSITIVE

  # PowerShell 7+ ONLY:
  #  'InvariantCultureIgnoreCase' is auto-converted to
  #  [StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase in this case.
  'A * IS BORN'.Contains($substring, 'InvariantCultureIgnoreCase')

  # Windows PowerShell workaround, via .IndexOf()
  -1 -ne 'A * IS BORN'.IndexOf($substring, [StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
  ```
- **`Select-String -SimpleMatch` is the superior alternative**, given that it **supports multiple *search strings* as well as multiple *input strings*** and also works in *both* PowerShell editions, case-*insensitively* by default (as PowerShell is in general), with a `-CaseSensitive` opt-in (still, introducing a substring-matching *operator* as well would help, both for performance and brevity):

  ```bash
  # Single input string, single search string.
  # Add -CaseSensitive for case-sensitivity.
  # -Quiet returns $true if the match succeeds.
  $substring = '* is'
  'A * IS BORN' | Select-String -Quiet -SimpleMatch $substring

  # Multiple input strings, multiple search strings.
  # Due to NOT using -Quiet, all matches are returned, similar
  # to the filtering behavior of -match with an array LHS.
  # `ForEach-Object Line` returns the matching *strings* only,
  # by extracting the .Line property value from the match-info objects.
  $substrings = '* is', ' A+'
  'A * IS BORN', 'Got an A+', 'Not me' | 
    Select-String -SimpleMatch $substrings | 
    ForEach-Object Line

  # Simpler PowerShell 7+-only alternative:
  # The -Raw switch returns the matching input strings directly.
  $substrings = '* is', ' A+'
  'A * IS BORN', 'Got an A+', 'Not me' | 
    Select-String -SimpleMatch -Raw $substrings
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Unlike with `-match` (with a single-string LHS), if there is *no* match, *nothing* is returned, but in a Boolean context such as an `if` statement that is equivalent to `$false`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Arrays aren't meant to be on the right side, but on the left is fine:

```
'Report', 'Global', 'Monthly' -match 'L'

Global
Monthly
```

I've seen this question with -match or -like few times.  People want this.  But it converts the right side to one string, and this ends up true:

```
if ('Report Global Monthly' -match 'Report', 'Global', 'Monthly') {
  $true
}

True
```

Select-string can take an array of patterns.  You can use "select-string -quiet", but any result ends up being true anyway.

```
if('Report' | select-string 'Report', 'Global', 'Monthly') {
  $true
}

True
```